# Jquery- Putting an attachment in form and send to email

Tags: php

I'm having a problem on how to add an attachment in my working form, i'm using **Bootstrap, JQuery and PHP.** i have no idea on how to add an attachment where the user will attach their Resume's and then send it to email.
i hope you can help me with this without changing my entire code. is it even possible?.

This is my initial input form

```
<section class = "resume section-padding" id = "resume "><div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="fName">First Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" placeholder="First Name">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "form-group col-md-12">
                                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "form-group col-md-4">
                                            <label for="doBirth">Date of Birth</label>
                                            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="doBirth" placeholder="Date of Birth">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "form-group col-md-4">
                                            <label for="city">City</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City">
                                          </div>
                                           <div class = "form-group col-md-4">
                                            <label for="zipCode">ZIP CODE</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="zipCode" placeholder="ZIP">
                                          </div>
                                           <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "form-group col-md-6">
                                            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                          </div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery it will get the value of the form.

```
$('.resume #getResume').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var fName = $('#fName').val();
            var lName = $('#lName').val();
            var address = $('#address').val();
            var doBirth = $('#doBirth').val();
            var city = $('#city').val();
            var zipCode = $('#zipCode').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var phone = $('#phone').val();
            var form = new Array({ 'fName':fName, 'lName':lName, 'address':address, 'doBirth':doBirth, 'city':city, 'zipCode':zipCode,
                                 'email':email, 'phone':phone });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/path/to/url.php",
                data: ({'action': 'resume', 'form': form})
            }).done(function(data) {
                $('#resume .result').html(data);

            $(".resume")[0].reset();
            });

});
```

This is my php this where my jQuery will pass the value

```
$sendTo = "email@email.com";

$action = $_POST['action'];

    $name = $_POST['form'][0]['name'];
    $email = $_POST['form'][0]['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['form'][0]['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['form'][0]['message'];

    if ($name == "" || $email == "" || $message == "" || $subject == "") {
        echo "<p class=\"error\">There was problem while sending E-Mail. Please verify entered data and try again!</p>";
        exit();
    }

    else
    {
        $header = 'From: ' . $name . '<' . $email . ">\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $sent = mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $header);

        if ($sent) {
            echo "<p class=\"success\">Message sent succesfully.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p class=\"error\">There was problem while sending E-Mail.</p>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: you want to have an upload file functionality?

Comment: yes that would be the case

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any framework and in core php it is very easy to upload a file. You can see all the code and working [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for better understanding. This is good source to get thing done.

In your current code just add a field to upload a file. Like this

`<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">`

. Also dont forget to `ON` the file_uploads in `php.ini` file.

**To add it in the email:**

for adding in the email just catch the file in the script file and send it  to the email like this.
`$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );`

Comment: where should i add the $email->AddAttachment ? in my php ? or in my jquery?

Comment: the resource/link i give you is actually a good approach for the core php mailing.  Yes this should be in the php side